Unable to retrieve latest artifact from GitLab CI pipeline when using branch as reference and name of job
I have a pipeline that has multiple jobs each producing two types of artifacts - headers inside include directory and library binaries inside lib directory. I download these artifacts during the configuration stage of a CMake project using FetchContent.
Since all artifacts from a pipeline end up in the same location unless instructed otherwise, I am thinking of adding a cumulative CI job that needs all other jobs and allows me to download all artifacts at once if everything is successful. So at the time the pipeline starts executing that cumulative job, all other CI jobs (if successfully completed) it depends on would have already stored their artifacts in the specific locations ready to be archived, downloaded unpacked and used.
According to GitLab Job Artifacts API documentation there are two ways of GETting the artifacts:

using the exact job ID
https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT-ID>/jobs/<JOB-ID>/artifacts


using the tag/branch reference plus the job's name
https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT-ID>/jobs/artifacts/<TAG|BRANCH>/download?job=<JOB-NAME>



The first possibility is not really useful in my case since I first need to retrieve the pipeline ID, then all the jobs and finally filter out the job that I am looking for. While the GitLab API can be used (and I have done this many times) in a CI job (incl. sorting and filtering as URL parameters!), I would like to avoid adding too much clutter if there is a better way.
The second option seems to deliver exactly what I am looking for. Both the name of the project and the CI job can be viewed as constants, meaning that this should in fact deliver the latest version of the artifacts in my cumulative job.
The problem is that I get
{
  "message": "404 Not found"
}

I assume that the group access token I was using for the first option (it works without a problem) should be applicable for the second one so I really don't understand what the problem is. Even if PRIVATE-TOKEN or similar was missing, I am expecting to get Permission denied and not Not found.
The name (both in the WebUI as well as in the JSON returned by the GitLab API) is correct. The repository currently has only main branch, so that's not it either.
[
  {
    "id": 7024131,
    "status": "success",
    "stage": "build-debug",
    "name": "build-debug-all",     <------- <JOB-NAME>
    "ref": "main",                 <------- <TAG|BRANCH>
    "tag": false,
    "coverage": null,
    "allow_failure": false,
    "created_at": "2024-08-09T06:31:55.117Z",
    "started_at": "2024-08-09T06:33:13.498Z",
    "finished_at": "2024-08-09T06:34:06.020Z",
    "erased_at": null,
    "duration": 52.521617,
    "queued_duration": 2.942895,
    "user": {
      ...
    }
    ...
  },
  ...
]

I also tried this on multiple of my other jobs (the ones that this cumulative one needs) and the result is the same.

There are number of issues that should be checked:

successful pipeline


Download the artifacts zipped archive from the latest successful
pipeline for the given reference name and job, provided the job
finished successfully.
Therefore, if you have a manual job that has blocked the pipeline and the pipeline is in blocked (or failed) state, it will not download it.


reference (branch or tag) is correct - check if the tag or branch exist and the pipeline is executed for it

token permission - make sure you have personal, job and/or group access token (depending on where the URL is called from) that works for the given project



I wrote it in my question that the first method (the one with an explicit job ID) works without any issue.
As for whether the pipeline was successful or not - also checked that. I used the same job that produced a valid artifact but with two different approaches - using job ID and using branch ref name and job name. First one succeeds, second one fails.

I realized I was calling main branch in the URL, even though I have 2 pipelines now, none of which for that branch. I extended your answer to make it more complete and also to hit closer home for my case in particular.
